What is this tree where flowers grow on the main branches?
Found in Durnstein, Austria yesterday.  I have never seen flowers seem to come from the main branches in such a vivid colour. What is this?


This is definitely a Judas-Tree, rather known as Cercis siliquastrum in the Family Fabaceae

Cercis siliquastrum , commonly known as the Judas tree or Judas-tree, is a small deciduous tree in the flowering plant family Fabaceae which is noted for its prolific display of deep pink flowers in spring. It is native to Southern Europe and Western Asia.Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercis_siliquastrum

This is a very beautiful find!

